# How do I write to Firestore using Angular 5?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, google-cloud-firestore

I've connected my Stripe checkout to Firebase Real Time Database by using this tutorial https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-stripe-payments-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-backend/

It is successful. However, I need the checkout process to work using Firestore since we have migrated our database there. Unfortunately, it is not working! The function works BUT the data is still being saved in Real Time Database, not Firestore. Here's my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

const db = admin.firestore(); // Firebase
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey) // Stripe

exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
                                .document('/payments/{userId}') 
                                .onWrite(event => {

    const payment = event.data.val();
    const userId = event.params.userId;
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId;

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return;

    return admin.firestore()
          .collection('payments')
          .doc('{userId}')
          .once('value')
          .then(snapshot => {
              return snapshot.val();
           })
           .then(customer => {

             const amount = payment.amount;
             const idempotency_key = paymentId;  // prevent duplicate charges
             const source = payment.testkey.id;
             const currency = 'php';
             const charge = {amount, currency, source};


             return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });

           })

           .then(charge => {
               db
               .collection('payments')
               .doc('{userId}')
               .collection('{paymentId}')
               .field('charge')
               .set(charge)
              })

 });
```

From part 1 of the tutorial, the database structure is like this:

```
payments
    $userId
        $paymentId
             amount: number
             token: object
             charge: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using firebase-functions >1.0.0

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Check full migration guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help!

I've tried these changes:
`// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` to `admin.initializeApp();`

`.onWrite(event => {` to `.onWrite((change, context) => {`

And I've added this:
`let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);`

It's still saving in Real Time DB. What else could I be missing? There are no errors when I do `firebase deploy --only functions`